# Getting more information from tasklist command

Tags: tasklist

As you might know, the command ***tasklist -fi "imagename eq explorer.exe"*** gives you the current values for **Image Name**, **PID**, **Session Name**, **Session#**, and **Mem Usage**. I'm using this command to log into a text file the current usage while doing a performance test. Which is great, but I also wanted to know if there's a way to also get additionally **USER Objects** and **Handles** values as well. Is it possible?